# Solving a nonlinear PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I wish to solve the following PDE:

$$
u_t - (u^{2})_{xx}=0
$$

with some boundary conditions which right now is not of much relevance apart from the fact that $u(t,x)$ is a piecewise continuous function and $u_x(t,0)=0$.

I have used the following substitution: $u(t,x)=f(\eta)t^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ and $\eta=xt^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ which reduces the above equation to a single variable of the form:

$$
\partial_{\eta}\left ( 2ff_\eta + \frac{\eta f}{3} \right )=0
$$

Now, I am very confused about how to proceed with this reduced form to solve the above equation and find the analytical solution of $f(\eta)$ thereby finding the analytical solution of $u(t,x)$.

Help of any sort is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\left ( 2ff_\eta + \frac{\eta f}{3} \right )=K$ for some constant $K$

Comment: This reduces the equation to the form: $ \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}+\frac{x}{6}=\frac{K}{y} $ and I am unaware on how to solve this (I am not even able to find any good resource on net). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, no, I just thought it would be easier as a order one DE

Comment: I don't think there is a general solution to the ODE which can be expressed in "simply functions". Wolfram Alpha gives an expression with airy functions and I think that's as "simple" as it gets. Please also note that the substitution you make to transform the PDE into the ODE is a hefty simplification. You will most likely lose many solutions and it might be no longer possible to fullfill the IC/BC with your special choice.

Comment: Also, I am fairly certain that the substitution does not yield the stated ODE, I think there is an error in your calculation, so you might wanna check that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but about the substitution part, it is totally correct. I have already checked it twice. Maybe you are right about the transformation part (that I should not have converted it into a single variable form) but I thought it would be easy to deal with a single variable.

Comment: The substitution is unfortunately not correct, I just calculated it myself. The $t$ does not dissappear. Please share your calculation so we can find out together where you went wrong.

Comment: Could you please clarify if it is $(u^2)_{xx}$ or $(u_{xx})^2$?

Comment: Apologies if you had any misunderstanding between $(u^2)_{xx}$ and $(u_{xx})^2$ but it is actually $(u^2)_{xx}$. I have also modified the equation accordingly. Now can you please recheck if the substitution is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there was a key point which we were missing from the question which would make the solution very easy (it clicked to me after spending 3-4 hours on this question) which is $u_x(t,0)=0$

Now, using the chain rule we can easily derive the following:

$$
u_x(t,x) = t^{-\frac{2}{3}}f_{\eta}(\eta)=0
$$

Also, from the very definition of $\eta$, $x=0$ implies $\eta=0$ and thus

$$
u_x(t,0) = t^{-\frac{2}{3}}f_{\eta}(0)=0
$$

or simply $f_{\eta}(0)=0$

Now, we can write

$$
\partial_{\eta}\left ( 2ff_\eta + \frac{\eta f}{3} \right )=0
$$

as (for a constant $K$)

$$
2ff_\eta + \frac{\eta f}{3} = K
$$

When $\eta=0$, $f_{\eta}(0)=0$ and thus substituting them in the above equation gives $K=0$ which makes our equation

$$
2ff_\eta + \frac{\eta f}{3} = 0
$$

Now, since we are not looking for the trivial solution, hence $f(\eta) \neq 0$ which means

$$
2f_\eta + \frac{\eta}{3} = 0
$$

or

$$
f(\eta) = -\frac{\eta^2}{12} + C
$$

for a constant $C$, which can be found from the other boundary conditions.

Comment: nice observation!

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, this is actually a rare bird: a nonlinear PDE for which you can separate variables. Dym's equation is another, but they almost do not exist. Let $u(t,x)=T(t)X(x).$ Then we have
\begin{align*}
\dot{T}X&=2T^2\!\left[(X')^2+XX''\right]\qquad\text{now divide by } T^2X:\\
\frac{\dot{T}}{T^2}&=\frac{2\!\left[(X')^2+XX''\right]}{X}=k,
\end{align*}
yielding the two ODE's:
\begin{align*}
\dot{T}&=kT^2\\
2\!\left[(X')^2+XX''\right]&=kX.
\end{align*}
The solution to the first is
$$T(t)=-\frac{1}{C+kt}.$$
The solution to the second is quite messy. Mathematica yields the following two solutions:
\begin{align*}
X(x)&=\text{InverseFunction}\left[\pm\,\frac{\text{$\#$1}^2\sqrt{3+\frac{\text{$\#$1}^3k}{c_1}}\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-\frac{k\text{$\#$1}^3}{3c_1}\right)}{2\sqrt{\text{$\#$1}^3k+3c_1}}\&\right][x+c_2],
\end{align*}
so essentially the inverse of a hypergeometric $_2F_1$ function. I don't know if this solution is of much use to you, as it's implicit. But it might yield some insight. Note: the $\#1$'s in the answer have to do with the InverseFunction in Mathematica. According to Mathematica's documentation:
$$\text{InverseFunction}[f][y]$$
gives the value of $x$ for which $f[x]=y.$ The $\&$ just means "pure function", which is what the InverseFunction first argument is expecting. You can effectively ignore that.

Comment: `#1` basically just means the first argument of said function. E.g one could write the function $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ as $\sqrt{\# 1}$ in Mathematica's shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to find your answer.  (Light a candle to Sophus Lie, who laid the groundwork in 1884.  Most of his ideas haven't been touched since.)  This algorithm has deep roots in the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, a counting theorem.  In the numerator, it's positive, and in the denominator, it's negative.  Thus we count, and set the result of each monomial equal to each other.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial^2 u^2}{\partial x^2}=0$$

$$u-t=2u-2x$$
$$u=2x-t$$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{Cx^2}{t}$$
Taking appropriate derivatives and substituting back into the equation gives us a value of $C=\frac{-1}{12}$
Therefore your solution is $$u(x,t)=\frac{-x^2}{12t}$$
This is easily verified and meets your boundary conditions.