# Solving First Order ODE $6yy'+xy=K$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any method prescribed (similar to Bernoulli's) to analytically solve (I am not able to find a suitable resource on the net) the following type of ODE:

$$
6yy'+xy=K
$$

where K is a constant. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: @metamorphy Actually, I was working on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237261/solving-a-nonlinear-pde) problem and as an intermediate stage, I got this equation.

Comment: This is a very abstruse ODE. Mathematica gives the solution implicitly in terms of the `AiryAiPrime`, `AiryBiPrime`, `AiryAi`, and `AiryBi` functions.

Comment: To add to Adrian's response, the ODE can be transformed to a linear ODE (of the Airy kind) in terms of $u(s)$ via the transformations $y=-3x^2+s$, $x=2ku'_s/u$.